Fix for from the legacy FCM API to the HTTP v1 API. #manage_relationship_maps_for_multiple_app_instances
For the end of the legacy FCM API,
We are fixing our Android app to change from the legacy FCM API to the HTTP v1 API.
We use the page as a reference: "manage relationship maps for multiple app instances"
Page LINK
When we send a request using the token we got, HTTP status of 401 was returned and are told that the authentication headers are invalid. It's an error.
I can't figure out why. Any ideas on how to get through?
I expect a HTTP status of 200 to be returned as a result of sending the request.
